# SQLException: Table not found in statement - Pentaho Saiku

Tags: mysql, pentaho, olap, saiku

I have created an OLAP cube using Pentaho Schema Workbench (followed this [link](http://codeissue.com/articles/a04edc3096d9c7d/introduction-to-mondrian-olap-schema)). There was no error in the cube. I published it, and when using saiku analyitcs, loaded the cube. The cube appeared in the list of cubes. then dragged the columns and rows, I got this error

SQLException: Table not found in statement [select "mondrian"."name" as "c0" from "mondrian"]

I checked the database, it has a table mondrian. I thought it is showing that because the schema name is not mentioned, so I added the schema name as well, then it still shows an error

SQLException: invalid schema name: mondrian in statement [select "mondrian"."name" as "c0" from "mondrian"."mondrian"]

Please help me with this error.

Comment: Is your schema named `mondrian` or `mondarin`? See `invalid schema name: mondarin in statement` in your question.

Comment: I am sorry, that was a typo. Now I have changed it to mondrian (the schema name) still I get the same error. "SQLException: invalid schema name: mondrian in statement [select "mondrian"."address" as "c0" from "mondrian"."mondrian"]"